# Problem styling Option[selected] in a select field

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a select box in which it is very important that the background for each option has a specific color. The problem is that the select box is clicked, the selected option appears blue (same as the selected text color).

I've tried using a lot of selectors (:active, :focus, ::selection, [selected]) and I cannot find the way to change this behaviour. Any idea?

I guess this can be done with js, but there must be a CSS selector that works, right?

[image: see what i mean?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't a dynamic CSS pseudo-class that changes selection depending on which `option` is selected. `option[selected]` only matches whichever `option`s have the `selected` attribute *as defined by the markup*.

Comment: I don't think `:selected` helps to actually change the blue "selected" colour he's talking about.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, CSS cannot help you with this. If this is "very important" to you, I think your only choice is to swap out the `<select>`s with JavaScript ones.

These ones look good:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/